# Find a string between two certain strings, capture the middle string and replace everything with new string in Python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I'm refactoring some code and I wanted to automate some of it using Python, here is what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have an initial string like 'void testsuite_testname(void)' and I want to substitute all of this with 'TEST_F(other_stuff, testname)'.

So, as you can see, I need to extract the testname from the first string and use it to create the new string.

So far, I'm trying to do this using regular expressions, here is what I have found to be doing the pattern recognition correctly:

`string = 'void testsuite_testname(void)`

`string2 = re.sub('void testsuite_(\S*)\(void\)', 'TEST_F(other_stuff, **??????**)', string)`

However, I don't know how should I backreference the \S* part. Any help will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: `r'TEST_F(other_stuff, \1)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re

string = 'void testsuite_testname(void)'

result = re.search(r"void testsuite_(\w+)\(void\)", string)

string2 = 'TEST_F(other_stuff, ' + result.group(1) + ')'


print(string2)

#Output: TEST_F(other_stuff, testname)
```

`string = 'void testsuite_testname(void)'` this is the first string.

`re.search()` the first argument is the pattern `r"void testsuite_(\w+)\(void\)"`, the second argument is `string` the string.

`result = re.search(r"void testsuite_(\w+)\(void\)", string)` search for a specific pattern in the string `string` then save the result of `(\w+)` inside the first capturing group `\w` means any word character it is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` this means match any character from `a` to `z`, or from `A` to `Z`, or from `0` to `9` or an underscore `_`, the `+` sign means match the previous token between one and unlimited times as many times as possible which means at least match one word character or more than one word character,so it will continue matching any word character after `testsuite_` until it reaches `(` of the `(void)` then it will stop and save the result `testname` inside a capturing group

`result.group(1)` this is how you can access the value inside the first capturing group.